# Receiveing Output of Command from Paramiko - Python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm creating a python script that SSH's into a linux box that runs a few commands.  I'm using paramiko for the ssh functionality.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ipadd, username='username', password='password')
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()

chan.send('find / -name "test"')
time.sleep(1)
resp = chan.recv(9999)
print resp

chan.send('find / -name "test1"')
time.sleep(1)
resp = chan.recv(9999)
print resp
```

The commands run successfully but when I want to receive the output (using chan.recv, it returns the following:

```
find / -name "test"
find / -name "test2"
```

I believe I should (and I need to) receive the output of the find cmd as a string.

```
/data/test
/data/test2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089498/can-i-capture-remotely-executed-commands-with-its-output-in-the-logfile-in-pytho      
Check this link if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had two things wrong.  First,

```
resp = chan.recv(9999)
```

should have been

```
resp += chan.recv(9999)
```

Second, I needed to send a new line before asking for a response

```
channel.send("\n")
```